# Database type to organize text fragments

Tags: sql, database, text, tags

What kind of database (or any other tool) would you recommend me to organize text fragments (typically entries in a journal), probably with images attached to them, and retrieve texts according to posting date, hashtags...?

I am not sure whether a relational database is the best option for this.

Answer (score 0):

"Your requirement is  journal entries with images and hashtags and retrieving texts according to posting date, hashtags" specific to these  requirements `MongoDB` (  `Document-Oriented Database` that stores data  in documents A document database is a type of `NoSQL` database that stores and manages `semi-structured data`. It uses internal structure within the document to extract `metadata`.  ) is 1 op. MongoDB is 100% free and `opensource`.Its got `full index support`, `replication` and `sharding`.  You can store `text fragment`s along with their posting date and `hashtags` as `fields` within a document. You can then query the `database` to retrieve documents based on their `posting date or hashtags` ( to be precise the `find()` method in `MongoDB` ). `Couchbase` is another similar option